# How to fix: CORS issue on SAML2 SSO on WSO2 Identity Server Service Provider?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have created a Servive Provider with SAML2 Web SSO.

I have a application with Node JS server and React Js Front End running on separate port 3000 (node) and 3001 (react).

There is a route "http://localhost:3000/app/login " on node that redirect to sso login page if the user is not authenticated (authentication managed by cookies).

But if I tried to invoke the api from the frontend the I am getting the CORS issue as following:

**Access to fetch at '[Here](https://IdentityServerIP:9443/samlsso?SAMLRequest=nVPBbtswDP0VQ%2FfYctJ5LhGnyJINC9BtRuLtsMugSGwrwJY8UW7Tv5%2FsxEMGrDnkJIB8j3x8pOZ3h6aOntGRtqZgaczZ3WJOoqlbWHb%2ByWzxd4fkowAzBEOiYJ0zYAVpAiMaJPASdssv9zCNObTOeittzaLNumC%2F1F5me4H5bM9zVFJmUmUs%2BjE2DIwAJOpwY8gL40OIp7cTnk%2FStOIZvMuBZ3GeZT9ZVJ5Kf9BGafN4Wcf%2BCCL4XFXlpPy2q1i0JELnQ%2BOVNdQ16HbonrXE79v7gj1530KSpO%2Bn8TSP0zjlU5hxzpN%2B6EQeGSxaBze0EX6Q33PoX1IKtzc3s4FEZNnRTBhGdGcuXhYvRqFssXs1Hh%2Bd8PhxW86Ts2rjnr4G%2BmZd2lrL12v29Mm6Rvi30WGqIaLV5GGAAjZC10ulHBIFV%2BvavqwcBokF865DlozSTteDaril4LrHw1W3tLJNK5ym3nQ8COlHY88Lr%2Brg2xYfrrH5IkyC7EuHcBmeF%2BtUf4oow2CVE4Za6%2FxpNf%2FTszjm3rDjb%2Fb8vy3%2BAA%3D%3D&SigAlg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F09%2Fxmldsig%23rsa-sha1&Signature=feiwE%2BzNGUlelJhs6ls2ga2RQTeT03ZzQu5j%2FbbqfgT1nLzQvau5rZlR1tbK%2FsKTbw6PFIYiOhCu%2BkC8ufWh5gRunun%2FsnnkvSIGy30Phs63DL%2BcquEzc1pNyN4gme5DEwJRiRRYc%2BkJ%2Bnjcn5C4QWAsi5cFD1aUPMQVvlszDcB8Tl%2Fko57TBWJqTCzJDcz1UKIBwQICQUo%2Bzqdl%2FSAS6JBeeHKXhvhwVmUVGonY%2FjWFORhli4bhk6kL%2BfJgr%2BocIC%2Be8TYJFFtEZZco0F5fzrDrBlg6%2FEZHlu0VkJNJlB5h%2FBnsrIFsFGoeMCJusr6WmqvtlusUW29QVaz8OdUikw%3D%3D)' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/app') from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.**

I tried this [solution](http://hasanthipurnima.blogspot.com/2016/05/applying-cors-filter-to-wso2-identity.html) also but no success.

Comment: Have you tried applying the cors filter as mentioned in http://hasanthipurnima.blogspot.com/2016/05/applying-cors-filter-to-wso2-identity.html to the **authenticationendpoint** web app in <IS-HOME>/repository/deployment/server/webapps/ directory

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue? If so please add the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in web my web-application which uses express as framewok
then I installed cors package available in npm [cors node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)
and used it in my server side script.

```js
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

Comment: Thanks. I solved the cors issue between react and node already like this. But there is issue on  between react and wso2 samlsso (redirection by node).

Comment: @Pujan can you explain the redirection issue with WSO2 IS? What I see only a application level issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be you are getting the issue while trying to access the /samlsso. To enable `org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter` filter in `repository/conf/tomcat/carbon/WEB-INF/web.xml` file, as mentioned in Tomcat [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html)

If you want to enable CORS headers for any other web app hosted in the Identity Server (such as `/authenticationendpoint` or `/oauth2`) you have to do the same in the web.xml files (in case of the authentication endpoint web application, the path is `repository/deployment/server/webapps/authenticationendpoint/WEB-INF/web.xml`) of those web apps as well.